# Is it possible to find out a value that is the most different with pure MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a list of url's and I want to find out the url that is the most unique. I mean which is appearing the fewest. Here is an example of the database:

```
3598 ('www.emp.de/blog/tag/fear-factory/',)
3599 ('www.emp.de/blog/tag/white-russian/',)
3600 ('www.emp.de/blog/musik/die-emp-plattenkiste-zum-07-august-2015/',)
3601 ('www.emp.de/Warenkorb/car_/',)
3602 ('www.emp.de/ter_dataprotection/',)
3603 ('hilfe.monster.de/my20/faq.aspx#help_1_211589',)
3604 ('jobs.monster.de/l-nordrhein-westfalen.aspx',)
3605 ('karriere-beratung.monster.de',)
3606 ('karriere-beratung.monster.de',)
```

In this case it should return jobs.monster.de or hilfe.monster.de. I only want one return value. Is that possible with pure mysql?

It should be some kind of counting of the main url before the ".de"

At this moment I do it this way:

```
con.execute("select url, date from urls_to_visit ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
```

Comment: Are they all .de websites? If so you would use a group by regex expression. Would give you an idea of how many times a base of the URL appeared in the list.

Comment: Yes only .de domains

Comment: But isnt there a way to do the counting and return of one url in one sql command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join the table on itself where ID's are not identical and count those, Then order by descending order and limit to 1 result.

not checked.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as hitcount,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.`url`,'.',2)  as url
   FROM table t1 
     INNER JOIN table t2 ON     
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.`url`,'.',2) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.`url`,'.',2) 
       AND t1.id <> t2.id 
 GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.`url`,'.',2)
 ORDER BY hitcount ASC
 LIMIT 1
```

**EDIT**

Just checked on this, and it doesn't quite work.

I came up with this alternative, which uses a subquery to group all the domains together and get a count.

```
SELECT subq.count as hitcount,SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.`url`,'.',2)  as domain
   FROM hits t1 
     INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as count, 
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(`url`,'.',2) as domain
        FROM hits GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(`url`,'.',2)
     ) subq
         ON subq.domain = SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.`url`,'.',2)
 GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.`url`,'.',2)
 ORDER BY hitcount ASC

 LIMIT 1
```

[working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/270af/8/0)

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample data (ignoring the parentheses, because I have no idea what those are doing), this query should do what you want:

```
select substring_index(url, '.', 2) as domain, count(*) as cnt
from table t
group by substring_index(url, '.', 2) 
order by cnt desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: At this moment I do it this way:  con.execute("select url, date from urls_to_visit ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")

Comment: I tried it but it gives back an error:     for row in con.execute("select substring_index(url, '.', 2) as domain, count(*) as cnt from table urls_to_visit group by substring_index(url, '.', 2) order by cnt desc limit 1;"):
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "table": syntax error